# Background image appers only in start-page, but not on others

Tags: css, visual-studio, razor

I created a web application in visual-studio, and in _Layout.cshtml I added:

```
<style>
body { 
       background-image: url("Content/bground3.jpg");
       background-repeat: repeat;
       background-color: #00ffff; 
}
</style>
```

For some reason, the background image appears only in the start-page but not in any sub-page, while the background-color does appear in whole pages.

I also tried to put an url of an image in external site, but I got the same result.
Any Idea?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share some more of your code? It is very hard to tell what is going on based only on what you provided.

Comment: @Amir I think the problem is you failed to put the right image path so they are not working! Here is a link that will help you a lot how to declare the image path properly. Though It's a  HTML tutorial but Image path works  same on CSS https://www.pagetutor.com/html_tutor/lesson10.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your subpages have other paths like your start page.

Since you use a relative path in your style tag, the target location will differ.

```
www.foo.bar/home.html
-> www.foo.bar/Content/bground3.jpg

www.foo.bar/subpath/subpage.html
-> www.foo.bar/subpath/Content/bground3.jpg
```

Please check your network protocol in your browser's devtools to see if the image source really can get fetched!
Maybe change the image source to an absolute path like `/Content/bground3.jpg`.

Comment: Well, watching the console gave me the clue. In one sub page I gave up the _Layout.cshtml, so any background won't appear there, and in other I overridded the body style and gave wrong path. Thx for help :)